Why did Sumireko Hanabusa create dolls of her former classmates?
Sumireko Hanabusa, an assassin, cybernetic robot mutant, and former war soldier, decided to create live dolls -- that moved around and tried to kill Tokaku-- of her former classmates. It is super creepy and gave me goosebumps, as I hate dolls. Sumireko Hanabusa create these dolls? Did she just not want to officially say goodbye to her classmates or was she "using them" in a creepy way? 
